# vim: strange issue when I yank a block with execute command

Tags: vim, exe, yank

Good Morning,

I have a strange issue when I yank a block with execute command.

I have created a small file with a few lines for testing

```
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
jkl; ;lkj
```

Ok it's not a masterpiece but for testing should work

When I am using the visual commands `Ctrl+v f; 4j y` 5 lines yanked

```
jkl;
jkl;
jkl;
jkl;
jkl;
```

expectable result!

Normally the command:

```
:exe "normal! \<C-v> f; 4j y"
```

should do the same. But there the result is:

```
jkl; ;
jkl; ;
jkl; ;
jkl; ;
jkl; ;
```

o_O Why?

A macro is workig normal. But I don't know how to find the stored macros in a human readable format.

Comment: Both `<C-v>f;4jy` and `:norm ^Vf;4jy` (`^V` obtained with `<C-v><C-v>`) produce the exact same result here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the argument to `exe` has *space characters* in it, and `vim` interprets those space characters quite literally.

```
:exe "normal! \<C-v> f; 4j y"
```

The space after the `f;` causes the cursor to move once forward, and the space after the `4j` causes the cursor to move again forward, capturing two extra columns which causes the extra space character and the extra `;` to be captured in the yank.

The following corrected version works correctly.

```
:exe "normal! \<C-v>f;4jy"
```

Note that the space after `<C-v>` *could have mattered* but did not matter in this particular example simply because the `f;` took the cursor further to the right than the first space did.